# Dictionary seems to keep inserted order

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-7.0

I’ve always assumed that a `Dictionary` does not preserve the order of which items are added.
Then why does this always seem to be true?

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        var l = new List<int>();
        var r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100_000; i++)
        {
            var j = r.Next();
            if (!d.ContainsKey(j))
            {
                d.Add(j, 1);
                l.Add(j);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(d.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).SequenceEqual(l));
    }
}
```

Comment: The current implementation preserves insertion order **provided no items are removed**. However, this is not guaranteed to remain true in the future

Comment: @canton7 From which version did this start? Is it documented?

Comment: msdn: For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: No, the documented contract is that the order is unspecified. The *implementation* happens to preserve insertion order provided there are no removals, but this is very deliberately **not** documented. This means that the implementation could change at any time

Comment: As to when this implementation was introduced: who knows. Before the BCL became open-source. You could disassemble old versions of .NET and take a look if you wanted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current implementation preserves insertion order **provided no items are removed**. However, this is not guaranteed to remain true in the future.

See e.g. [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=net-8.0#remarks):

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified

For example:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict.Add("A", "A");
dict.Add("B", "B");
dict.Remove("A");
dict.Add("C", "C");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dict.Values)); // C B
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwBYBuY4gNwmXIBMoBjBcgXnJgBTAO7kAIlwRQA9jBYBPADxVScSnlIA+ABQBKekWIduAOgCCbNtoBEZ62tvX9Ryecs2AQvfLWvzosYIJgBKgmDSjII2dv6BblbWAMLeSU4GxFQAnNoqJgBS0rA2PmpxAGoQADaoggDOuv5AA==)

(The dictionary stores keys and values in an array of entries, and the iteration order is the order of entries in the array. Normally items are appended to the array. However, if an item is removed, it creates a linked list of empty entries and new insertions get added to the first empty entry: this avoids copying everything around when an entry is removed. This leads to "C" being added to the first empty entry, which was left when "A" was removed. Of course, this is just the current implementation and could change at any time.)

Comment: *"[...] provided no items are removed."* -- More precisely the insertion order is preserved if no more items are added after at least one item is removed. Removing items alone doesn't destroy the order of the remaining items.